# How to set a Flatpage as the Homepage in Django

Tags: django, django-flatpages

How can I set a Flatpage as the Homepage?

My urls.py is

```
    (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

In the admin section I set the URL of the Flatpage to "/".

I get this error

> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.

I'm guessing setting the URL to "/" is wrong, but can't find an example of the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the entry from the urls.py and this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: The FlatpageFallbackMiddleware is what does all the url work for the flatpages app.  If a 404 is raised, the middleware checks all your flatpages for a page that matches the url and sends that back rather than the 404.